# Find the shortest path to reach a given destination cell in 2D matrix with obstacles

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I am working on below interview question and I am confuse on how to use BFS search here. I am confuse on how to deal with the blockades here?

> Given a MxN matrix find the shortest path to reach a given destination
>   cell. The robot can move up, down, left or right. The matrix also
>   comes with set of blockades in few of the cells where the robot can't
>   pass through. Output the minimum number of moves the robot needs to
>   make to reach the destination. Output -1 if the destination is not
>   reachable. Assume that the blockade will never be at the starting
>   cell.
>
> Input Format: First line contains the values of M and N matrix. Second
>   line contains the cell location of the robots starting position. Third
>   line contains the cell location of the destination. Fourth line and
>   the lines following that will contain the locations of the blockades.
>   The example below contains only one blockade at (2,2) where the robot
>   can't pass through.  Below is the input:

```
3 3
1 1
3 3
2 2
```

Output should be 4 for above input.

Below is what I have started but confuse on how to deal with blockades here while doing BFS search:

```
  public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int M = sc.nextInt();
    int N = sc.nextInt();

    int startX = sc.nextInt();
    int startY = sc.nextInt();

    int destinationX = sc.nextInt();
    int destinationY = sc.nextInt();

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        int blockedX = sc.nextInt();
        int blockedY = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you can also use depth first search for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply view the grid as a graph: each cell is connected to its four neighbors (or fewer if it's on an edge), excluding any blockades. Using your example:

```
  1 2 3
1 • • •
2 • x •
3 • • •
```

we have the graph (using (row, col) notation):

```
(1,1) <-> (1,2)
(2,1) <-> (3,1)
(3,1) <-> (2,3)
(2,3) <-> (3,3)
(3,3) <-> (3,2)
(3,2) <-> (3,1)
(3,1) <-> (2,1)
(2,1) <-> (1,1)
```

where all edge lengths are 1. Now you can apply a standard [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) from the start node until you reach the target node, keeping track of which nodes you visit. In pseudocode:

- Mark all cell distances as infinite except for the robot starting cell, which has distance zero (you can do this using an extra 2D array, or maybe even in-place depending on how you store the grid).
- Initialize an empty queue of cells Q
- Add the robot starting cell to Q
- While Q is not empty:

  - Dequeue the next cell C from Q
  - For each non-blockade neighbor N of C (easy to determine from grid):

    - If N's distance is infinity, mark N's distance to be (C's distance) + 1, and add N to Q.
    - If N is the destination cell, return N's distance.
- At this point we know there's no path from the start cell to the destination cell.